# Difference between nil and (nil) in LISP

Tags: common-lisp

I've just begun learning LISP and was trying to solve the following problem:
(I've tried solving the problem until the point I got this doubt and got stuck)

Original List : ((b c)(r p))

Perform the following operations on this list and output the result:

1. CDR - ((r p))
2. CADR - (r p)
3. CDADR - (p)
4. CDDADR - for this operation is the answer (nil) or nil? 
   Should it be (NIL) because it denotes an empty list? As 'D' extracts all elements from the list except the first one. Or is there absolutely no difference between nil and (nil)

Thanks!

Comment: You could just try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `NIL/(NIL)`:

- `NIL` is a self-evaluating symbol (one of the symbols where `symbol-value` is itself). All functions that operate on booleans recognize this symbol as *false*. All functions that operate on sequences or cons cells recognize this symbol as the empty list. In fact, `nil` is used in other contexts (format, etc.) and you can define your own functions where `nil` could mean anything (by convention, it is often meant to be "empty", "zero", "undefined", ...). Evaluating `(list)` returns `nil`.
- `(NIL)` is a list of one element, `NIL`.

  It can be obtained by evaluating `(cons nil nil)`, or `(list nil)`. If you apply `length` on it, it returns 1.

When you *read* this form:

```
((b c)(r p))
```

... you obtain the same structure as if you *read* this one:

```
((b . (c . nil)) . ((r . (p . nil)) . nil))
```

... which is also the same structure as if you *evaluated*:

```
(cons ;; CAR
      (cons ;; CAAR
            'b
            ;; CDAR
            (cons 'c
                  nil))
      ;; CDR
      (cons (cons 'r
                  (cons 'p
                        nil))
            nil))
```

Then, remember that:

```
(CADR X) = (CAR (CDR X))
```

... and follow each cons cell accordingly. For example:

```
(CDADR X) = (CDR (CAR (CDR X)))
```

You evaluate from inside-out and apply each function on its previous result, which will descend into the tree of cons cells accordingly, starting from the root element.
In other words, start at the root element, descend into the CDR, take the CAR of the result, etc. I'll let you do this. The result is neither `(NIL)` or `NIL`.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are wrong:

List: `((b c) (r p))`

```
Operation  your example    actual result

CDR        ((r p))         ((r p))
CADR       r               (r p)
CDADR      (nil) or nil    (p)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I realised my mistake after going over some more material, I'll correct the question.

Comment: @crazyCoder Please don't fix the question after you receive feedback from answers (avoid [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)), or at least be very explicit about why you edited something in your question (e.g. "update:" sections). That will help other readers understand what is going on when answers and questions seem to talk about different problems. If the answer helped you solve a part of your problem, fine, but don't hide that problem in an edit; that would be confusing.

Comment: @coredump Sure, as I'm new to StackOverflow I am not acquainted how exactly things work on this platform. Thanks for the tip. Will keep in mind for next time!